How to prove that a specific quadric intersection is complete and irreducible?
Let's borrow the quadric intersection $I$ from another question. More precisely, let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $\neq 2$ and $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n \in k^*$ be some pairwise different non-zero elements. Consider the quadric intersection $I := \big\{ y_i^2 - y_0^2 = a_i \big\}_{i=1}^n$ in the space of dimension $n+1$ in the variables $y_0, y_1, \cdots, y_n$. I checked on a computer that for the first values $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the variety $I$ is an irreducible curve, that is, a complete intersection. How to prove that observation for every natural $n$? Is $I$ smooth in addition?

You might want to specify that the $a_i$ are all non-zero if you want irreducibility.

Thanks! I made the correction.

So now, the answer is that it is a complete intersection because each relation involves a new variable, and it's non-singular by the Jacobian criterion.

Could you please explain in more details your phrase "it is a complete intersection because each relation involves a new variable"?

Yes. For a complete intersection, you need to know that each relation is a non zero-divisor modulo the previous ones. If it involves a new variable not present in previous relations, this is automatic.

The intersection of $I$ with a general hyperplane in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ is clearly a finite set. Is this argument mathematically strict for $I$ to be a curve?
